# Which reference first mentioned about 'a rule of thumb' for k value of k-NN algorithm?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

Lots of articles and threads are saying that

> 'a rule of thumb' for $k$ of $k$-NN is $k=\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of samples.

I'd like to see which paper or related material first mentioned it.